# Pytest не видит пакеты импортированные в модуле, откуда импортируется функция для теста

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, импорт, pytest

Написал модуль, написал для него тесты. Запустил - проходят. Запустил программу - не работает. Ошибка импорта. Вернул то, как было, но теперь тесты не проходят.
Репозиторий: https://github.com/PC-Nazarka/maze-solver

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Тесты импортируют ваш maze_solver как пакет, значит внутри maze_solver нужно использовать  относительный импорт через `.constants` или абсолютный импорт `maze_solver.constants`, при чем во всех импортах. Ну и запускать тогда как пакет через `python -m maze_solver`

Comment: @insolor, пробовал. У меня не работало это. В смвсле относительный и относительный импорт

Comment: Я вечером возможно посмотрю. Если до этого кто-то не ответит.

Comment: @insolor, пофиксил, путем добавления pytest.ini. Уже залил в реп

Answer (score 0):

1. Все пофиксил путем создания файла `pytest.ini` со следующим содержимым:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = ./maze_solver
```

2. Так же сработал относительный импорт, т.е. в основном пакете через `.`. Но проект теперь запускать с помощью `python -m maze_solver`